# Como remover o último caractere, guardar o resultado numa variável e usar a variável fora do foreach?

Tags: php, variáveis, loop

Eu tenho um código `PHP` assim:

```
foreach ($rows as $obj) :

    $all_ids = $obj->ID . ', ';

endforeach;
```

.. cujo a saída é `125, 148, 157, 169, 185,`

Como remover a última virgula e guardar o resto da saída numa variável para usá-la fora do `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) para remover o ultimo caracter a direito, o segundo argumento diz qual deve ser o caracter.

**Trim**

```
<?php
   $rows = array("125", "148", "157", "169", "185");
   $all_ids = "";
   foreach ($rows as $item){
      $all_ids .= $item.", ";
   }

   echo trim(trim($all_ids),',');
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/DeuvOl)

---

**substr**

Ou com substr, que removerá o espaço e a virgula.

```
<?php
   $rows = array("125", "148", "157", "169", "185");
   $all_ids = "";
   foreach ($rows as $item){
      $all_ids .= $item.", ";
   }

   $all_ids = substr($all_ids, -0, -2);
   echo $all_ids;
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/16UPw0)

---

**array_map**

A partir do php5.3 é possível utilizar funções anônimas, que combinada com [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) elimina o foreach. `array_map` aplica uma função em todos os elementos de um array(`$row`), a função anônima apenas devolve a propriedade `ID` do objeto, depois basta usar o [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) para converter o array em uma string separada por virgulas, igual demonstrado pelo Jefferson Silva.

Essa abordagem foi tirada de [PHP - Extracting a property from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1118994/1342547)

```
<?php
   //Monta um array igual ao da pergunta
   $valores = array("125", "148", "157", "169", "185");
   for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
     $obj = new stdClass();
     $obj->ID = $valores[$i];
     $rows[] = $obj;
   }

   $all_ids  =  array_map(function($item){ return $item->ID; }, $rows);
   echo implode(',', $all_ids);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/HExDNe)

Comment: Por mais simples que pareça não deu certo. Você reparou que essa string é o resultado de um foreach?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius, ele está sobrescrevendo o valor? fica so último é isso? nesse caso troque o `=` por `.=` que vai concatenar a string.

Answer (score 3):

Eu costumo utilizar uma abordagem mais simples quando quero transformar um array ou objeto em uma string separado por virgulas.

```
<?php
   $rows = array("125", "148", "157", "169", "185");
   echo implode(',',$rows); //125,148,157,169,185
?>
```

Comment: obviamente a melhor opção para a pergunta colocada.

Answer (score 2):

Embora a resposta do @rray seja bastante simples e útil, também existe uma outra maneira de conseguir o resultado desejada. Utilize-se um `bool` para saber se um ítem é primeiro ou não na lista.

Um exemplo:

```
<?php
   $rows = array("125", "148", "157", "169", "185");
   $all_ids = "";
   $first_row = true;
   foreach ($rows as $item){
      if ( $first_row ) {
       $first_row = false;
       $all_ids .= $item;
      } else {
       $all_ids .= ", ".$item;
      }
   }
```

Isso é bastante útil em linguagens que não tenham uma função `trim()` que aceite valores além do espaço.

Comment: Se não puder usar o `trim()` é bem útil esse código, também possível fazer com regex.